# Calculate total number of weeks and days between two dates?

Tags: javascript

Such that it will display 1 Week 6 days

Code:

```
var d1 = tblLNMP.rows[0].cells[1].getElementsByTagName("span")[0].innerHTML;
var d2 = tblLNMP.rows[0].cells[3].getElementsByTagName("span")[0].innerHTML;
var date1 = new Date(d1);                                               
var date2 = new Date(d2);
var timeDiff = Math.abs(date2.getTime() - date1.getTime());                             
var diffDays = Math.ceil(timeDiff / (1000 * 3600 * 24));
var numberOfWeeksAndDays = diffDays / 7; // Will return decimal
```

Example:

```
date1 = 07/01/2014
date2 = 07/14/2014
Should display 1 Week and 6 Days but with my current code it returns 1.8xxxxx
Getting the number of weeks I suppose is easy but getting the number of days if not     divisible by 7 is a challenge for me.
```

Please bear javascript noob.

Comment: Do you know about the modulo operator? `var numberOfDays = diffDays % 7`.

Comment: Can you please share the link of the duplicate question. Thanks

Comment: It's at the top of your question.

Comment: It's at the top of the question text.